# Mac "wx/wxprec.h" file not found

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, wxwidgets

While trying to build a project with cmake, i get the error wx/wxprec.h file not found.

Went to the wx/ sub directory to check the files and only had the setup.h.
Copied the wxprec.h file from wxwidgets git and manually placed there , still get the same error we+hen building.

Also, i did sudo make install in the /build of [this](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets) wxwidgets version.

Comment: did you build wxWidgets yourself? What version of the library you are trying to use? Can you try to build with just g++ `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` *.cpp -o <program_name> and then create an application bundle? Also, remove any extra files you put into the wx tree - you don't need them. Keep in mind - `CMake` is not officially supported way of building either wxWidgets or an application that uses it.

Comment: I downloaded the wxwidgets from the git project I linked in the question, from there I just followed the standard method of running ../config and make in the build folder.

Comment: you should create a new build directory and do build there. The directory called `build` contains internal build files for Makefile generation and MSVC solution files. After you complete the build do following:

Comment: `cd <your_project_name> && g++ ``~/wxWidgets/buildMac/wx-config --cxxflags --libs`` *.cpp -o <your_project_binary_name>`. Then create an application bundle if the application is a GUI one and you are done. No need to use 3rd party thing like CMake.

Comment: Ok i correctly followed the instructions this time, create a new `build-cocoa` folder, ran the `../configure` and the ran both `make` and `make install`, but still get the same error when building the project.
I'm not sure i can build that way, it is is no way similar to the instructions given, if it helps im trying to build [this project.](https://github.com/MisterTea/HyperNEAT)